# Understanding Core Data and Saving an NSManagedObjectContext after a deletion

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-data, io, nsmanagedobject

I have a core data generated class, 'item'.  It has a property of 'type', which is another class.

I have customized 'setType' so that some other processing takes place - for example I update the 'dateTypeLastSet'.  This is working fine so far.

However, for some reason, this additional processing is happening also when I delete the item.  Specifically, it doesn't happen until I call 'save' on the NSManagedObjectContext.

Is this because the deletion causes an automatic call to 'setType:nil'?  Logging the parameters shows that NULL is the attempted assignment.

This is going to be problematic for me, since amongst my additional processing code I perform some calculations.  Let's pretend I store some counter of 'number of times an item's type is set' in there.  I don't want the deletion and setting to nil to be counted.  But I also can't just check for nil, since this might be a legitimate update (nil as a type might be acceptable).

Any explanations or advice is appreciated.

UPDATE

It turns out that when type is deleted, it does indeed set that attribute to nil - I noticed that the data entity's delete rule is nullify by default.  If change it to no action, I don't have this problem.

So the question now becomes - what are the other effects of changing the delete rule from nullify?  Why is this seen as the sensible default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that nullify is a sensible default because, once the 'type' no longer exists, having a stray pointer to it could be dangerous.  If you look up the NSNoActionDeleteRule in the docs, it says:

> "If you use this rule, you are responsible for maintaining the
>   integrity of the object graph. This rule is strongly discouraged for
>   all but advanced users."

Comment: Then I just don't understand how it is possible to have custom code in my setType method, since it will always get called when I delete the item.

Comment: I guess it depends on the difference between nil as an explicit setting and nil as a value that the system needs to use.  Can you define a 'type' object that is a null value and use it for the explicit setType:?  ...sort of the way NSNull is used?

Comment: I could.  I just feel icky about it I guess.

Comment: The other way of thinking about it is, what would you want to have happen if Core Data wasn't there.  Object x has a weak reference to object y and y is dealloc'ed...?

Comment: You're right, I would want it to be nil. I guess this problem is only specific to custom code inside a setter for an attribute with same name as the attribute it sets, if that makes any sense.  For example, if my custom code was all in side a method called setTheType: instead of setType:, and I made sure I always used setTheType: in my code, then setType: would revert back to purely setting the primitives, which is what I went to happen when the item's deleted. The same thing could be achieved if on the data entity I named the type attribute something like TypeCoreData. Gets a bit ugly though.